# Sonar Scanner option to include the project properties values in scripted pipeline itself

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins Freestyle JOB we have execute SonarQube Scanner section, In that we have option to include the sonar-project analysis properties, Similarly is there any way available to define/declare the sonar-project.properties in scripted pipeline itself? As I want to maintain the below properties values in my CI-System itself.

```
sonar.projectName= 
sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectVersion=
sonar.projectDescription=
sonar.projectBaseDir=
sonar.sources=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shell/batch script according to your OS and while running sonar-scanner command just pass the arguments as shown below:-

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName=Project-Name -Dsonar.projectKey=Project-key -Dsonar.projectVersion=PV -Dsonar.projectDescription=PD -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=PBD -Dsonar.sources=sources
```

For more details please click [sonarlink](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: can you please rate the answer also :)

Comment: Can define a property for tag too? e.g -Dsonar.projectTag=mytag or somthing else?